# Screen won't rotate in any apps on my Nexus 6

Tags: auto-rotation

So, quite some time ago I upgraded my Nexus 6 to Android 6.0.1. At that time, my screen rotation worked fine. A few days ago, I noticed I couldn't rotate the screen in Snapchat or on other social media apps. Even things like YouTube wouldn't rotate automatically. I know the hardware is working fine because there are readings from the gyroscope sensor and the screen breath's when its picked up or moved too much. Any one have any idea?

Comment: I don't think Gyroscope sensor is used for orientation. See [Which hardware sensors are supported by Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/29221)

Answer (score 0):

Just download accelerometer monitor app from Google play, and literally slap the back of the phone kinda hard. It has fixed many others! Source : reddit

Comment: Please link the source